# WebSockets not working with DNS

Tags: html, websocket

I have an web application, that I am using websockets with. I have a problem with using ws://myDomain.com as an address of my websocket server. The problem is weird, because I tested the connection using many PC's, and it seems that this works with about 1/5 of them! When I change the websocket address to be ws://111.111.111.111 (my server ip addr), then 100% of clients work fine.

Has anyone maybe had similar problem? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a proxy in-between that does support websockets.  This could be because the proxy is out of date or the websocket server isn't 100% up to spec.  What server are you using?  Try switching to WSS (TLS with websockets).

Answer (score 0):

You could have a cross-origin resource sharing issue. Or maybe the PCs that can't connect are on different subnets and that can't resolve myDomain.com. Try nslookup myDomain.com from those PCs.